# "error: too few arguments to function"

Tags: c, function, opencv, default-value, arguments

I have a C program called opencv2.0 function :

```
cvSaveImage( out_img_name, img);
```

Compiler gcc reports that

> too few arguments to function cvSaveImage

The prototype of cvSaveImage in highgui.h is

> CVAPI(int) cvSaveImage( const char* filename, const CvArr* image, const int* params CV_DEFAULT(0) )

After I change my call to be

```
cvSaveImage( out_img_name, img, 0);
```

The compilation is finally successful. Does it mean default values of arguments for function are only supported in C++ but not C?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I guess that just happens in new versions of opencv, I didn't get this error with the old version available on ubuntu repositories, but when I compiled the new version, the code that used to run gave me the error you are talking about

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Correct - Standard C does not support default arguments, neither in the C89 standard nor in the C99 standard (nor in the C2011 standard).  There may be compiler-specific extensions to support it in some compilers, but it is not standard.

Comment: I was writing my C programs using project templates available for C++ language in Visual Studio. For a while I kept writing it and the moment I turned on the setting `Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Compile As` to `Compile as C code (/TC)` my `gets_s` code started throwing the error mentioned in this thread. Then I had to explicitly pass integer values as second argument of `get_s` to make it compilable.

Answer (score 2):

C requires a special notation if you want to use a variable number of arguments.

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Varargs.html

You can't define a default variable to be passed in to a plain function. You could set-up a macro that auto-magically passes in a default value and use that as your function entry if you want to.